# Inline autocorrect with contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

Is it possible to make something like the autocorrect feature in iOS for contenteditable fields? As the user types, spelling would be checked (I already have this part), but then I need a way to correct the word. I could replace the whole html of the contenteditable, but then cursor position is lost, and there is a possibility that the user would try to type before html is rewritten. Ideally, this would just replace x characters before the user's cursor. Is this possible?

Comment: it's possible, but more complicated than you might think. consider that `document.getSelection().anchorNode` will tell you only the node where the typing is happening. you need to replace the text of the whole node, and then restore the cursor to the place it was before, which will be a different index if the corrected text's length changes. show us some code and we can help get it working.

Comment: @dandavis I don't have any code - I have absolutely no idea how to do this, and so far I can't find anything. Even a description of how restoring the cursor along with anchorNode would be much appreciated.

Comment: pretend you were typing and put the cursor before "and", like "textt |and", then click the button in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/p0dxdnub/

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! (You should put that as an answer so I can mark it as accepted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the core replace-in-node-being-typed in feature can be powered by this function:

```
function runRep(from, to) {
    var sel = document.getSelection(),
        nd = sel.anchorNode,
        text = nd.textContent.slice(0, sel.focusOffset),
        newText = text.replace(from, to),
        wholeNew = nd.textContent.replace(text, newText),
        range = document.createRange();

    nd.textContent = wholeNew;
    range.setStart(nd, newText.length);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    nd.parentNode.focus()

}
```

usage: `runRep("helo",  "hello");`, which will replace a mis-spelled "hello" to the left of the cursor in the current node. you need to be careful about sub-string matches. Upgrading the replace() to use a RegExp would likely allow more precise targeting (like only whole-words, ignoring cAsE, etc), but this will work as-is and the RegExp upgrade doesn't change the rest of the code.

not shown is how one actually detects the mis-spelled words, which is another topic...

obligatory fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p0dxdnub/